# Can I resize the backlog item description panel in TFS web view?

Tags: team-foundation-server

In the product backlog item view in TFS, the "description" panel is tiny relative to the size of my screen, and annoyingly there's lots of unused space at the bottom of the page. Since the description is the important part, I'd like to see more than a few lines of it at a time. Is there a way to resize this panel, or better yet to show the description on its own, full screen and without all the other clutter?

Comment: How many lines can you see? What browser do you use?

Comment: I can see 13 lines of text, but the main point is that the description box occupies roughly 15% of the page. Annoyingly, there's as much unused space at the bottom of the page as there is in the description box!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using TFS 2013 and unfortunately it looks like there's no way to resize the description panel, its size seems to be fixed and part of the overlay backlog item window.

Each panel (Description, Business Context, Originated By, etc.) has its own link, e.g. `$/<team_project>/_backlogs#witc_tab_417`, `$/<team_project>/_backlogs#witc_tab_422`, `$/<team_project>/_backlogs#witc_tab_428`, but trying to open one of those links in a new tab causes the whole backlog item view to be displayed again.

As a workaround, the only thing that I'd suggest to do if you have a long description is to temporarily copy it entirely (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and paste it (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) into an external editor (e.g. Notepad++) and then read it from there.